# Ionic capacitor remove REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission for android build

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-permissions, capacitor

We are creating apps using command

```
ionic build --configuration=development && ionic capacitor copy android --no-build && npx cap open android
```

Now latest android policy tells us to remove `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` this permission.

How I remove same permission.

Tried to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove"/>
```

In file app/src/main/mainfest file

But when I hit command for build , still I can saw

capacitor-corodova-android-plugin file/mainfest/mainfest file

How can I remove that?

Answer (score 8):

Using `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove"/>` should be enough, but it won't remove the entry from `capacitor-corodova-android-plugins` mainfest file as that's the original file with the permission.

What you have to check is the merged manifest.

Open the `app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` with Android Studio. There is a "text" tab and a "merged manifest" tab.
Click "merged manifest" you will then see how your final `AndroidManifest.xml` file will look like when installed in a device and the permissions shouldn't be there.

Comment: I already tried this.And also in merged mainfest this permission is not there.Still my apps are rejected with this.Is there any more step which I can perform?

Comment: make sure you have deleted other apks you uploaded earlier with the permission, it's probably rejecting your app because of that

Comment: @JulioCeasr If I delete that will it affect my released current version?

Comment: Last app which is our released version has that permission. But the latest build which I tried to upload is going for rejection.You can refer this query
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73958249/we-found-that-your-app-is-not-compliant-with-how-request-install-packages-permis

Comment: check any previous upload in alpha or beta channels

Comment: I removed this permission still my app is rejected due to same reason.Is there any more steps which I can perform to approve my build?

Comment: Had to search `node_modules` to find the offending plugin and remove the `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` permission from the `plugin.xml`. To finalize the change and make sure it didn't keep coming back, we used [`patch-package`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) to create a patch that is applied as a `postinstall` script in `package.json`. Worked a treat.