# We found that your app is not compliant with how REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission is allowed to be used

Tags: ionic-framework, google-play-services, google-play-console, ionic-native

Our app is built in Ionic / Capacitor.

I got this mail when I submit my latest app.[image]

Our latest app is rejected.I try to resubmit app and also try to appeal but nor I got response nor my updates are approved.

In our latest bundle I try to add

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove"/>
```

So now our app not contain this permission and also now that is not shown in below permission
[image]

But still my app is rejected after this.Is there any place from where I have to remove this permission?

Comment: Any solution will be helpful?

Comment: @aswanthbonthala Yes.I have to remove this permission from mainfest file using 

` <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove"/> `

Then I have to re upload latest build on all the active track.What I had make mistake is that I upload latest build only on closed testing track not on production track. I had to upload same on production track also.After that my build was approved.

Comment: @VaibhavShah thanks, this helped me, also part of the problem was that I was trying to do a phased rollout so it was still taking into consideration the previous release, I had to choose full rollout (100%) to stop this happening.