# Violation Request Install Packages Permission: Permission use is not directly related to your app's core purpose

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-permissions, capacitor

Violation Request Install Packages Permission: Permission use is not directly related to your app's core purpose.

We found that your app is not compliant with how `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` permission is allowed to be used. Specifically, the use of the permission is not directly related to the core purpose of the app.

Previous answers recommended in

[Ionic capacitor remove REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission for android build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73900475/ionic-capacitor-remove-request-install-packages-permission-for-android-build/73904250)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove"/>
```

In the AndroidManifest.xml

Or removing from Android Manifest.xml Merged Manifest Tab, which has no reference to

`android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES`.

The only Cordova plugin I use is localforage-cordovasqlitedriver

list of capacitor plugins,

[image]

How do I effectively search through the plugins and project to find which one is adding `android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES`.

I also found

public static final String REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES = "android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES";

in ~/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-32/android.jar!/android/Manifest.class

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73900475/ionic-capacitor-remove-request-install-packages-permission-for-android-build/73904250

Comment: I tried those answers and they did not work

Comment: Look at the source code for the plugins. If you have some that are closed source, temporarily remove them and see if the resulting APK has the permission (via `adb` or [apps](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.oF2pks.applicationsinfo/)). If you determine that your closed-source plugins are the culprit, add them back in one at a time until you see which one requests the permission.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what I found,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove"/>
```

adds the permission into the manifest-merger-release-report.txt.

Note this report will show any plugins that add the REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGE

So yes it is removed from the App, but the report says the REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission is in the App and that is enough to get rejected by Google Play store.  Also any previous releases in

Open testing,

Closed testing,

Internal testing,

Or Production

That has REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGE will cause the App to be rejected even though the Request Install Package is not present in your new release

see

https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/issues/869